# When User Logs In It Displays Exception: User does not have permission to perform this action

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

The website worked fine when I was debugging and running it in Visual Studio 2010 and when I published it to my IIS server and run the website again to log in typing a username that does exist it gives an exception. Here is the website below if you would like to navigate the website here is the link below:

http://monsterhunter445.no-ip.org/

**Edit: I am using the regular login controls that is used by asp.net and the account was created with the remote administration tool which created this ASPNETDB.MDF. I am guessing its permission error but I have no clue because I am new to web development and asp.net**

Comment: You need to provide much more information to make this question possible to answer. What login system are you using? How did you publish? How are existing accounts pushed to the new site during publish? A good introduction to SO question can be found at http://tinyurl.com/sohints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay after a week of hard work I finally fixed the problem by removing the "User Instance=true" from the connection string. I do not understand why that worked but it worked.

Answer (score 1):

This error originates from the SQL server.

Check your connection string and make sure the account specified in the connection string have permission to access the database.

If you use integrated security, make sure the account that runs your website has access to the database.

Comment: In in my connection string it says Integrated Security=SSPI. What does that mean?

Comment: That means that the login credentials of the application running is used to authenticate to the database. Check what account runs your application and add that account as a user of the database.

Comment: Is the login credentials of the application the same as a windows username and password?

Answer (score 0):

When you published the website it is likely the database that was installed on the production (I suppose) environment has been recreated and is different from the one you have locally. This means that any users you created while debugging are now gone. Try creating users on the remote instance of the application.

*If this doesn't work, look for the connection string that you are using in Web.config and try to connect remotely to that database. Check to see if the aspnet_users (I think that's the name) table contains anything.*

Comment: I tried that thinking that was the case but it is not.